# Slow application startup when dynamically populating GridView

Tags: gridview, qml, qt5, qt-quick, qtquick2

I'm trying to populate a GridView by dynamically filling a ListModel in QtQuick 2.0 (Qt 5).
It works, but the application starts very slowly:

The application window appears instantly, but it takes about 2 seconds for lightblue background to appear. Until then I see a default gray background.

If I uncomment the two lines which are commented below, the app starts instantly. But I don't like this hack because I can't understand why it works.

Does anybody have any idea what could be wrong?

Thanks!

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 1024; height: 600
    color: "lightblue"

    Component.onCompleted: {
        //moviesModel.clear()
        moviesModel.append({ "movieNumber": 1 })
    }

    ListModel {
        id: moviesModel
        //ListElement { movieNumber: 0 }
    }

    Component {
        id: moviesComponent
        Rectangle {
            width: grid.cellWidth
            height: grid.cellHeight
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: movieNumber
            }
        }
    }

    GridView {
        id: grid
        anchors.fill: parent
        cellWidth: 100
        cellHeight: 200

        model: moviesModel
        delegate: moviesComponent
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you populate your model? Via multiple `append` calls?

Comment: Yes, but it's reproduced even if there is a single append call, exactly as in the code above. To reproduce, create a new QtQuick 2.0 project and copy-paste the code into main.qml.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a moot point. Your code with the lines uncommented creates a List Model with one element. Your onCompleted then deletes all content from the list and appends in a new element. It seems like you should either have a static ListModel defined in QML, or you should have an empty list model at startup.

Every time you change a ListModel and it has elements that are visible there are a number of things that happen. The ListModel needs to update its internal structure and then signal it has changed. Then your grid view needs to re render visible ListElements via the delegate. It may be that the act of two very quick changes(the clear and the append). Which both require all these actions to be executed after each, is just too much on startup.  Remember, you only have one thread available for the gui.

Comment: The strange thing is that my code with lines uncommented works properly. So it's an exact opposite of what seems logical. :)